Applications cannot access network drives
First post here and I have been stuck with this issue for a few weeks now. No amount of Googling and looking at forums have been able to solve it yet, but then again, I am a noob to this and just recently switched to Linux.
The issue: Applications cannot see network drives even if I copy paste the locations into the bar. I can see my drives just fine in Nautilus, though, so I have no idea what is going on.

As you can see in the image, on the left side is Nautilus where you can see the network drives just fine, but the application file manager shows something completely different. It doesn't show any network drives and shows a completely different home folder. I don't even know why it says 16GB.
Sorry if this has been asked a million times. I haven't been able to find another thread on this issue, and I am completely stuck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Your 'other locations' will only show discovered items not currently mounted remote drives.  This includes SMB, CIFS, etc. shares.  This was how GNOME decided to make Nautilus and such work

@ThomasWard ahh ok, so does that mean it is pretty much impossible for me to connect to my smb shares, or am I missing something?

Which Ubuntu are you using?  Because in Nautilus on 24.04 it shows an option to add servers by location.

FYI, In Ubuntu 24.10, they file chooser and file manager can be the same app.

@ThomasWard I am using 24.04, do you happen to know a guide or anything that I can follow on this? I still haven't found anything to fix the issue
